# using jQuery show and hide options of one select box from the value selected of another select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 select boxes one is called Countries and other Called States

here is sample of Countries Select Box

```
<select name="Country" id=Country">
<option value="">Select Country</option>
<option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
<option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
<option value="CA">Canada</option>
<option value="UK">United Kingdon</option>
<option value="US">United States</option>
</select>
```

I am running small javascript based on jQuery that if the country selected is CA and then in the States Select Box just display all the options of Canadian Provinces, other wise for any other country just display the default US States

here is the sample States Select Box

```
<select name="StateSelect" id="StateSelect">
<option value="">Select State</option>
<option class="us-states" value="AA">Armed Forces - Americas</option>
<option class="us-states" value="AE">Armed Forces - Europe</option>
<option class="us-states" value="AP">Armed Forces - Pacific</option>
<option class="us-states" value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option class="us-states" value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option class="us-states" value="AZ">Arizona</option>
<option class="ca-states" value="AB">Alberta</option>
<option class="ca-states" value="BC">British Columbia</option>
<option class="ca-states" value="MB">Manitoba</option>
<option class="ca-states" value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
<option class="ca-states" value="NF">Newfoundland</option>
</select>
```

here is  my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { $("#Country").change(function () {
if($("#Country").val()=='CA'){
$(".us-states").css("display", "none");
$(".ca-states").css("display", "block");
} else {
$(".us-states").css("display", "block");
$(".ca-states").css("display", "none"); 
 }
});
</script>
```

The problem is the script works fine in FireFox but any other browser like Chrome or IE it does not work at all, when I select the country as CA it just does not display the Canadian Provinces.

What am I missing? thanks and appreciate any advice :)

Comment: Use http://api.jquery.com/show/ and http://api.jquery.com/hide

Comment: Works fine over here, you have made some typo's though. id="Country" is missing a quotation mark and you forgot to end your .change() function with }); see: http://jsfiddle.net/sLWmj/

Comment: Thanks guys but still does not work in Chrome or IE when I select CA the only thing that displays select state nothing else in Chrome and in IE always display just the US states. Thanks

Comment: Did you check the console tab for errors in your developer window (F12 in chrome)?

Comment: Yes I checked both the console tab as well resources tab no errors or warnings

Comment: I know the script is firing because if I do page view source its appending css display block to all the Canadian Options and display none to rest but its bizzare it wont show the options

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#Country").change(function () {
    if($("#Country").val()=='CA'){
        $(".us-states").hide();
        $(".ca-states").show();
    } else {
        $(".us-states").show();
        $(".ca-states").hide(); 
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

However the reason is that you've missed on }); at the end. You closed Change but not Ready

Comment: Thanks guys but still does not work in Chrome or IE when I select CA the only thing that displays select state nothing else in Chrome and in IE always display just the US states. Thanks

Comment: If you are using the .css method, try to make them !important it may work